# Nginx regex rewrite rule is not working

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a problem with my rule, I want this link

http://www.example.com/mobil/?h=galatasaray-muslera-nin-yedegini-buldu-haberi&HI=1050764#detail

Redirect To

http://www.example.com/galatasaray-muslera-nin-yedegini-buldu-haberi-1050764.html

My Rule is:

```
rewrite "(.*)(\/mobil\/)?h=(.*)&HI=([0-9]{7})(.*)" /$3-$4.html last;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `(.*)mobil\/\?h=(.*)&HI=([0-9]{7}).*$` replacing with `\1\2-\3.html`

Comment: The query string is not part of the normalised URI used by `rewrite` to match its *regular expression*. You do not need to capture the values of `h=` and `HI=`, as they are already available as `$arg_h` and `$arg_HI`.

Comment: I have changed my rule as below and now its working but the browser link does not changed. Is there any missing in my rule ?

    rewrite "(.*)\/mobil\/(.*)?(.*)" /$arg_h-$arg_HI.html last;